# tailwindcss - relative class causing hover conflict

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a button in where when you click on it, it toggles a drop down menu. I also want it to change colors when you hover over it. I am using a `relative` class to create the toggle menu. However, when I use that class, the button doesn't change colors. Is there a way to have these two effects play nicely with each other?

code:

```
<div class="mt-4 ml-8">
                    <div class="relative w-[122px] overflow-hidden">

                        <div class="btn bg-primary opacity-0 text-white border-primary border-2 hover:bg-white hover:text-primary">Cryptocurrency
                        </div>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="peer absolute top-0 inset-x-0 w-full h-10 opacity-0 z-10 cursor-pointer" />



                        <div class="overflow-hidden transition-all duration-500 ml-4 max-h-0 peer-checked:max-h-40">
                            <div class="bg-gray-200 rounded">
                                <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="/mining">Mining</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/hodl">HODLing</a></li
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Your input is right on top of your text, so the hover doesn't work. Is there a reason why you aren't using JavaScript to do this? It'd be more flexible as well. I don't really think a hardcoded 122px will do you any good in the future when you want to add more.

Comment: You are probably right in that I should use JavaScript. I am relatively new to tailwind and the code is loosely based on a YouTube tutorial I followed. I will use JavaScript. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use CSS/HTML only you may use [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) HTML tag which will work in pair with input - provide `id` for input and `for` for label

```html
<div class="mt-4 ml-8 bg-gray-800">
  <div class="w-[122px] overflow-hidden">

      <label for="menu" class="btn block text-white border-2 hover:bg-white hover:text-yellow-400">
        Cryptocurrency
      </label>

      <input id="menu" type="checkbox" class="peer hidden" />

      <div class="overflow-hidden transition-all duration-500 ml-4 max-h-0 peer-checked:max-h-40">
          // ...
      </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/avK7WxAN55)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using jQiery but I appreciate the help